# Mock request/post with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, junit4

I am having trouble covering the following function '**postJson**' with tests (JUnit/Mockito), and can't find a way to mock the line `response = getTarget(path).request().post(entity, Map.class);`

```
//Constructor
public HttpService() {
    this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
}

Client client;

public Map<String, ?> postJson(String path, Map<String, ?> data){
    Map<String, ?> response = null;

    try {
        Entity<Map<String, ?>> entity = Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        response = getTarget(path).request().post(entity, Map.class);   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.toString());
    }

    return response;
}

public WebTarget getTarget(String path){
    return client.target(BASE_URI + path);
}
```

My test currently

```
@Test
public void postJsonTest(){
    assertEquals(null,new HttpService().postJson("", new HashMap<String,Integer>()));

    //Verifica se a função de comunicação com servidor é chamda
    Map<String,String> resposta = new HashMap<String,String>();
    HttpService mock = spy(HttpService.class);  

    assertEquals(mock.postJson("",resposta),null);

    Mockito.verify(mock,Mockito.atLeast(1)).postJson("", resposta);
    Mockito.verify(mock,Mockito.atLeast(1)).getTarget(Mockito.anyString());
}
```

I can't find a way to make the test code after the 'request()' onwards. Anyone can give me an example/explain how I can go about covering this function with mockito ?

Comment: Added in the post, the client is an attribute in the class

Comment: The client is already instantiated in the constructor of the class

Comment: Your problem is the static method call in the constructor.  You might want to have a second constructor which doesn't call this.  Then you could pass a mock in that constructor, where the `target` method is mocked.  You'll want a mock of `WebTarget`, and also a mock of whatever `request` returns.

Comment: I'll write a full answer if I have time later, and if nobody else does.

Comment: I edited the question, i just cant put my finger on how to cover anything after the request on that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given this additional constructor on `HttpService`:

```
public HttpService(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}
```

The following test will pass:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HttpServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Client client;
    @Mock
    private WebTarget webTarget;
    @Mock
    private RequestEntity requestEntity;

    private HttpService httpService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.httpService = new HttpService(client);
    }

    @Test
    public void postJsonTest() {
        String path = "/a/path";
        Map<String, ?> data = new HashMap<>();

        // the postJson method features this chained call: getTarget(path).request().post(entity, Map.class)
        // so we have to mock each object created in that chain

        // covers getTarget(path)
        Mockito.when(client.target(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(webTarget);

        // covers request()
        Mockito.when(webTarget.request()).thenReturn(requestEntity);

        // covers post()
        Map<String, Object> expected = new HashMap<>();

        Mockito.when(requestEntity.post(Mockito.any(Entity.class), Mockito.eq(Map.class))).thenReturn(expected);
        Map<String, ?> actual = httpService.postJson(path, data);
        Assert.assertSame(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This relies on providing a new `HttpService` constructor which accepts a `Client` instance.
- The existing approach of instancing `Client` via a static method call inside the `HttpService`'s no-arg constructor requires use of PowerMockito. A more test friendly approach is to provide a constructor which accepts a `Client` or perhaps a `ClientFactory` with the default implementation of the `ClientFactory` being `ClientBuilder.newClient()`
- The `postJson()` method features a chained call (`getTarget(path).request().post(entity, Map.class)`) which requires us to mock each object returned in that chain i.e. `Client`, `WebTarget` and `RequestEntity`
- My example skates over specifics such as the generic type of `RequestEntity` and the choice of exact argument matchers vs. general argument matchers. You'll be able to make the right choice there since you know most about (a) the specifics of your implementation and (b) the intention of your test but the above test at least shows you that mocking a chain of calls requires each object in that chain to be mocked.

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what I had in mind with my comments.  Thank you for saving me the trouble of writing this myself.  Upvoted.